# Get ArrayList value and set it to a TextView on Button Click Not Working - RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, onitemclick

My last question hopefully for this week.. I have set up a `RecyclerView` with an `Array` that iterates through numbers 0 - 350 in increments of 10. This pops up as an overlay over the activity by clicking a `TextView` (dailyGoal). Once a value has been selected, the chosen value should be set to the `TextView`.

This is all working fine, the value does set, however it sets the value as the first value, which is 10 mins. I think this is because the `onItemClicked` is pointing to the `RecyclerView` as a whole and not the Recycler `TextView` (time), there is a method included for it, however whenever I try to use it, the `onClick` function does nothing..

I think this one is a simple solution but I've been messing around with it for a while and can't find a working solution..

**Activity**

```
ArrayList<String> dailyGoalTime;
int[] timeArray = new int[360];

    dailyGoal.setText("60");
    dailyGoalRecycler.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    dailyGoalTime = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < timeArray.length; i++) {
        timeArray[i] = i;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < timeArray.length; i++) {
        if (i % 10 == 0 && i != 0) {
            dailyGoalTime.add(i + " mins");
        }
    }

    ItemClickSupport.addTo(dailyGoalRecycler).setOnItemClickListener(
            new ItemClickSupport.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v) {
                    dailyGoal.setText(timeArray[i]);
                    dailyGoalRecycler.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onItemClicked(TextView time, int position, View view) {
                    // this does nothing
                    
                    // dailyGoal.setText(dailyGoalTime.get(timeArray[i]));
                    // dailyGoalRecycler.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
        );
```

**Interface**

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {

    void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v);

    void onItemClicked(TextView time, int position, View view);
}
```

**Adapter**

```
ArrayList<String> dailyGoalTime;
ItemClickSupport.OnItemClickListener listener;

public DailyGoalAdapter(ArrayList<String> dailyGoalTime) {
    this.dailyGoalTime = dailyGoalTime;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public DailyGoalAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DailyGoalAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.time.setText(dailyGoalTime.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dailyGoalTime.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView time;
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        time = itemView.findViewById(tvTime);
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following everything correctly, but this might be the issue: `dailyGoal.setText(timeArray[i]);`. Seems like you meant to set `timeArray[position]` instead. I can't see where that `i` is declared, at least. Those in the loops are out of scope at that point, and wouldn't really make sense there anyway.

Comment: @MikeM. I tried that before sending this, should have added that sorry. The app crashes `onClick` with error `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x3` at `setText` method. I have seen answers where the for loop was inside the button click but like you say, I don't think that makes sense?

Comment: Right, 'cause `timeArray` is `int`s. I didn't see that. However, the given code should still be throwing that same Exception, I would think. In any case, for that specific Exception, it's because you can't set arbitrary integer values with that method; it's expecting a resource ID. To set a random integer value, you just need to convert it to a `String` first; e.g., `dailyGoal.setText(String.valueOf(timeArray[i]));`. I'm not sure if that's the only issue you currently have, though.

Comment: This is what I had earlier but was showing me 10 mins (first value), now it is setting the `dailyGoal` to 0 instead. No errors however.

Comment: Sorry, not `i` there. You want `position`: `dailyGoal.setText(String.valueOf(timeArray[position]));`

Comment: Wait, that is because I had decared `i` as an integer, it would display null.

Comment: Okay, thats doing something! It is displaying the array position of the textView (recycler): 0, 1, 2, 3 etc

Comment: Well, that's how you're filling that array: `timeArray[i] = i;`. You might want to log its contents while you're fixing this, to make sure it contains what you mean for it to.

Comment: I thought I was filling it like so: `dailyGoalTime.add(i + " mins");`

Comment: Did you mean to do this instead: `dailyGoal.setText(dailyGoalTime.get(position));`?

Comment: Thats the one! I could have sworn I tried that already.. my tired brain must have decieved me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the most important part. You need to call the interface method on item click like this:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        listener.onItemClicked(holder.time, position, holder.itemView);
    }
)};
```